# Netbeans has no display on my computer

Tags: opensuse, java, display-settings, dwm, ide

I installed netbeans using `zypper install netbeans`. Trying to run it, I get the "loading" splash screen which is proceeded by a small popup which asks me if I want to register my copy and receive some benefits. Once that popup is gone, I'm left with a big beige screen and nothing else. It's almost like netbeans can't be displayed. Running `netbeans` from the command line does not give me any output or error messages.

I also had this same issue when I was trying to install it using the `.sh` file found on their website.

I'm running opensuse 11.4 with dwm as my window manager. I'm also using the AMD's fglrx graphics driver (I have also experienced this issue using the default open source driver shipped with opensuse).

**EDIT** When trying to run `sudo netbeans`, I get:

```
/usr/share/netbeans/6.8/bin/../platform11/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set
```

And no display. This is not same behavior as when I launch as a regular user.

Comment: The error when running as `root` just means `root` doesn't have the `$DISPLAY` environment variable set. Run a root shell, `export DISPLAY=:0`, and you should see netbeans startup (with the same display bug if my answer is correct).

Comment: Your answer is correct, however `root`'s `$DISPLAY` is already set to `:0`, which is the same as my normal user.

Comment: The environment you get with `sudo` is not the same as if you run a login shell. You could try with `sudo -i`.

Comment: Doing `su` and `echo $DISPLAY` gives me `:0`. Doing `sudo -i echo $DISPLAY` also gives me `:0`

Comment: What does `sudo -i netbeans` do?

Comment: Gives me the same error message as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the same type of problem for `awesomewm` and probably quite a few other window managers.

The `dmw` wiki has a section on this: [Fixing misbehaving Java applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dwm#Fixing_misbehaving_Java_applications). The solution proposed is to change the window manager name by installing `wmname`, and then running:

```
$ wmname LG3D
```

If that works, make sure that is called at every X session startup.

The `awesomewm` wiki has this same suggestion, and other workarounds that are most likely relevant to `dwm` here: [Problems with Java](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java).